# How do I find a minimum sample size for the proportion test / T test?

Tags: statistical-significance, python, t-test, sample-size, statistical-power

What I want to figure out is how to find a minimum sample size for comparing a sample to the whole population when the ratio of the sample to the population is less than 5-10% (e.g. 30 to 1000).

The population in the question is everyone who answered a particular survey question and can be between 800 and 1500 responses for most questions. This population then can be broken into many smaller sub groups with different sizes ranging from 5 to 200, with the average group size being around 30. A question has multiple choices (which could be assumed as being somewhat uniform), so for simplicity let's say that each question has 5 choices, with an average probability for each choice about 20%.

What I need to find out or somehow quantify is what's the minimum number of sample size that I can compare to the whole population numbers while still retaining the statistical significance but also the practical significance...

For example: if the sample size is 10, and n responses for choice #1 = 3, while the population size = 1000 and n responses for choice #1 in the whole population = 100 then the proportions I get is 30% vs 10% which has a p-value from z-test of 0.0375 which is less than alpha and hence significant... but at the same time it might be just a sampling error...

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportions_ztest
proportions_ztest([3,100], [10,1000]) 
#p_value = 0.0375..
```

So in this case, what method should I use for choosing the minimum or optimal sample size when comparing largely different n and N?

I have done the power analysis for this purpose and have found a minimum sample size to observe a certain effect, and it seems that 10 to 1000 is fine... but I was curious if there is something else?

Python code for the power analysis:

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import TTestIndPower
analysis = TTestIndPower()

nobs1 = 1000
effect = 0.8
alpha = 0.1
power = 0.8
ratio = 0.01

result = analysis.solve_power(effect_size=effect ,nobs1 = nobs1 ,  alpha = alpha, ratio = ratio)
print('Power (1-Type II Error): %.3f' % result)

result = analysis.solve_power(effect_size=effect ,nobs1 = nobs1, power = power ,  ratio = ratio)
print('Alpha Level (Significance): %.3f' % result)

result = analysis.solve_power(effect_size=effect , power = power ,  alpha = alpha, ratio = ratio)
print('Sample Size: %.3f' % result)

result = analysis.solve_power(power = power , nobs1 = nobs1 ,  alpha = alpha, ratio = ratio)
print('Effect Size (0.2 - Small, 0.5 - Medium, 0.8 - Big): %.3f' % result)

result = analysis.solve_power(effect_size=effect ,power = power , nobs1 = nobs1 ,  alpha = alpha, ratio = None)
print('Ratio: %.4f' % result)
```

Output:

```
Power (1-Type II Error): 0.808
Alpha Level (Significance): 0.094
Sample Size: 976.976
Effect Size (0.2 - Small, 0.5 - Medium, 0.8 - Big): 0.791
Ratio: 0.0098
```

Comment: Roughly speaking, if the sample size $n$ is not more than 10%-20% the population size $N,$ then for the length of a confidence interval, the difference between sampling with and without replacement is not great. When $N$ is very much larger then $n,$ the exact choice of the size of $n$ largely governs the lengths of CIs and the power (ability to detect true differences) for tests. // I'm being very general here. If you have specific examples in mind, please edit them into your Question, for more useful feedback.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the comment, I edited the question with more examples and rephrased the question a little bit. Could you explain a bit more on how to find a minimum sample size using the CIs?